# How to know in Android if a device has a barcode scanner

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have a requirement i should display different UI's if a device has a in build scanner , So far i can know the device model and manifrature name , by using `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER` or model etc from hardware information it is not giving if the device has a `barcode scanner`  any idea how can we tweak this in experience & idea would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is nothing in the Android SDK about whether a device has a built-in barcode scanner.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that typically these types of devices use non-free proprietary drivers, which are a pain in the arse to work with

Comment: @commonWare is it possible to know by using some sensor information for laser scanner

Comment: @AbhijitChakra: I am not aware of any such sensor, sorry